# Can I get project build command in intellij plugin?

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio, intellij-plugin

I'm trying to make plugin for **Intellij**.
Can I get project build command in plugin? (like `make dist` or `gbs build --include-all`)

And does it works for **Android Studio**?

Answer (score 1):

In IntelliJ IDEA, to build a project, call

```
CompilerManager.getInstance(project).make(null);
```

Android Studio does not use IntelliJ IDEA's build system, so you need to call a different API:

```
GradleInvoker.getInstance(project).compileJava(moduleManager.getModules());
```